# Unidentified network connection error when connecting a laptop to a pc

Tags: networking, ethernet

I've been using a bridged connection, between my laptop's WiFi and PC through ethernet, for a couple of months and I had to do a factory reset of the pc a few hours ago. But now I can't get the connection to work. On both sides I get "Unidentified network" and the troubleshooter indicates ""Ethernet" doesn't have a valid IP configuration". I've tried different Ethernet cables, a lot of cmd commands and network settings, but I can never get rid of the Unidentified network! Does anyone know how to get this setup to work (like it once used to)?

[image]

Comment: You didn't mention OS and version, but Windows 10 v. 1903 has caused "network connectivity issues after installing update KB4515384". See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-fix-network-adapter-after-installing-update-kb4515384-windows-10

Comment: @DrMoishePippik thanks for you comment, I apparently was still running an older version of Windows on both laptop and pc, and it still didn't work. Updating also didn't :[